# retrieving data from array

Tags: c#, arrays, indexing

I have `byte[] array Q` that contains some data.To convert the array to string I'm using `result=System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Q);` The result is something like `JOBID: 196035002\n` .I need only the integer part of it. Is there a way to get only the `int` value `196035002` without converting to string and splitting into another array?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Based on the code snippet, I'd say C#.

Comment: Is `JOBID:` always at the start?  If it is, then you can manipulate the string with String functions and convert the number to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the language you are talking about is C#. What you need to do is:

```
char[] delimiterChars = { ':' };
string[] words = result.Split(delimiterChars);
foreach (string s in words)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
```

Comment: OP specifically stated "**without** converting to string and splitting into another array", so while your answer works, it's not what they were looking for.

Comment: @Tim: That is actually true!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use functions like `Split` then you can try this regex to get the desired output.

```
 String inputString = "JOBID: 196035002\n";
 Int32 result = Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Match(inputString, @"\d+").Value);
```

NameSpace for Regex: `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;`